# Android studio 2.2 cannot found Cmake for NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake

i am using windows 7-64bit OS
Want to integrate NDK, Get help from [NDK installation steps](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental/migrate-to-stable)

Cannot find out Cmake which required for Ndk
Can any one help me to get Cmake, without cmack its giving error
Find screen of sdk tools [image]

Comment: did you try from the standalone sdk manager?

Comment: @AndroidMechanic standalone sdk doesn't have option regarding NDK, Cmak, LLDB etc.

Comment: Might be worth filing a bug: http://tools.android.com/filing-bugs.

Comment: @DanAlbert may be bug, i found that 32 bit Cmake have not support from sudio but i have 64bit then it must be

Comment: Move out cmake directory inside SDK to trash or other dir, then re-run that sdk manager in android studio, could you see the cmake option?

Comment: Did you install NDK before? I can't see it on the screenshot.

Comment: @J.D.1731 no i haven't install NDK Before first time i am tring to install but its not display

Comment: I am facing the same problem, did you get the solution.

Comment: @TusharRai sorry no solution found, i have replace my sdk with other sdk which have this option